# output answer by rounding off in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm

In a programming contest i got a task to print my output this way but i couldnot figure out the correct method to do this.How can we do this in c++?Suppose my output is stored in a double  variable and i need to follow this pattern or format

If output is supposed to be 0.0034567, output should be "3.457 3".

If output is supposed to be 0.3034567, output should be "3.034 1".

Comment: `if (output == "0.0034567") std::cout << "3.457 3": else if (output == "0.3034567") std::cout << "3.034 1"'.

Comment: most programming contests what to see how you are able to solve the problem, and not how you are able to ask other people to solve it for you.

Comment: show what you've got so far

Comment: @PeteBecker the values i need to deal with is stored in a variable

Comment: Hint:  search the web for "c++ exponent of number".  There are various ways to get the power or exponent of the number.

Comment: @kolaveri - if I was being nasty I'd point out that `output` **is** a variable. But the point is that you haven' t provided anywhere near enough information for anyone to understand what you're asking for.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews - that's part of the solution, but the rounding is funky. Don't know whether that's a typo or a serious requirement.

Answer (score -1):

You can use trunc to truncate to a certain number of digits, use
 #include < cmath >

```
double output = 0.0034567;
int count=0;

while (output<1)
{
    output *=10;
    count++;
}

output*=1000;
int modul =(int) output%10;
if (modul>=5)
    output++;

output /=1000;
output = trunc(1000 * output)/1000;
std::cout << output << " "  << count << endl;
```

Comment: `while (output<0)` looks wrong. I'd say `while (output<1)`.

Comment: @Simon with your code the output is 3.46 3 for input 0.0034567 but it should be 3.457 3

Comment: With the addition of that call to `std::trunc` it gets the wrong answer for `0.0034567`.

Comment: Ok I should read more carefully. I was not thinking this would be so strange task... I thought it would be just formatting without rounding.
Finally it should work

Comment: How is that an improvement over the comment that I gave in response to the original question? In other words, what rules are you applying to determine how to cut off the text? Or is this just hacked code that produces the "right" answers for those two values?

Comment: No, I assumed that it is basic formatting without rounding in first place. After your comment to my answer only thing which has "logic" for me was that the rounding is based on the actual number. 5,6,7,8,9 = ++. But yes, without further details it is just "right" answer... thank you for the -1 btw